# How to post image to facebook wall using graph api

Tags: android

I am having a bitmap in my Activity and I tried to convert this into a String like below

Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data");

```
  strpostimageurl=   BitMapToString(bitmap) ;
```

//method to convert bitmap to String

```
  public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
     byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
     String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
     return temp;
```

}

And I am sending this String to Facebook Graph api Like below

```
String res=  

UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/"+Login.facebookid+"/feed?access_token="+accesstoken+"&method="+"post"+"&message="+"hi"+"&picture="+strpostimageurl);
```

But I am getting illegal Character response

```
12-06 14:47:16.488: E/post response(21627): Illegal character in query at index 281: https://graph.facebook.com/100001574672236/feed?access_token=AAAGaMRblwW4BAOdRuZCHNSxtpAPd8O05fXBDY0yF10sWf7tv1wlW7xX6WituirF6g7bZAMCflHPb5qLzeNYOmItEZBzeewNZBNF09KrpZBgZDZD&method=post&message=hi&picture=iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAALcAAAChCAYAAACF4S4ZAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFU
```

How to send Bitmap to Facebook api to show an image

Comment: I want to use Graph api because I have to post on wall of multiple friends

Comment: you can only share image with image url by graph api. Graph api will not support to Base64 string images.

Comment: Can I convert Bitmap to image url

Comment: you can upload that bitmap to some server and get image url from your server.

Comment: You can use service like Amazon s3 to upload images and get live url for your image.

Comment: Is there any other option for me

Comment: with graph api most probably no.

Comment: can I use Sdcard path to send as a url

Comment: local urls are not allowed with Graph Api. try with facebook sdk it will solve your problem.

Comment: As I said in my previous post,I need to send the post to multiple friends by using their facebookids

Comment: you can do that by use of friend id with facebook sdk. You can loop through your friend list and access each of friend id to post picture on his/her wall.

Comment: I really have no idea on facebook sdk,can you please provide me some code to do this

Comment: Follow this link : [Android Facebook Tutorial ] (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)

Comment: This can be useful to for reference : (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6707583/556975)

Comment: Accept my comments if its being helpful to you somehow.