# How to post sdcard image into facebook wall using graph api

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to post image to facebook wall using graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740692/how-to-post-image-to-facebook-wall-using-graph-api)

I am using Graph API to post on Facebook wall.

```
strpostimageurl=/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera1354795516555.jpg

String res = UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/"+Login.facebookid+"/feed?access_token="+accesstoken+"&method="+"post"+"&message="+"hi"+"&link="+strpostimageurl);
```

I am getting Bad Request as a response.

Is it possible to give SD-Card path for Posting images? I am having only Bitmap of the object, so I created file with that Bitmap and I am using that.

And I need to post on multiple friends wall,so I am preferring to use Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the *Bad Request* error because you are passing the wrong values to the Facebook API.

First, if you are uploading an Image / Photo via a link or an URL, then you have to use the *"source"* tag and **not** the *"link"* tag as you have in your code.

Second, if you were to fix the above, I doubt the code would work seeing that your `strpostimageurl` does not actually have a valid URL.

Third, since it is not a valid URL, using the `"source"` tag would not be an option. You will need to use something like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmpImageGallery.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

Bundle postImgGallery = new Bundle();

// ADD THE PHOTO DATA TO THE BUNDLE
postImgGallery.putByteArray("photo", baos.toByteArray());

// ADD THE CAPTION FROM THE STRING finalStatusMessage TO THE BUNDLE
if (finalStatusMessage.equals(""))  {
    /*****  DO NOTHING HERE     *****/
} else {
    postImgGallery.putString("caption", finalStatusMessage);
}

mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", postImgGallery, "POST", new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
```

Here,

1. `mAsyncRunner` is an instance of the `AsyncFacebookRunner Class` that is part of the Facebook SDK.
2. `bmpImageGallery` is an instance of a `Bitmap` in which the Image selected by the user is stored. It gets the Image selected by the User from the gallery using:

This is code runs on the `OnClick` event of a `Button` that opens the Gallery and lets the User select a Photo / Image from it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, reqcdGalleryImage);
```

Then, using the `onActivityResult()` method, the selected image is passed to the `Bitmap` instance `bmpImageGallery` used in the code earlier:

```
bmpImageGallery = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), targetURI);
```

**EDIT:**

Then try this (OnClick) :

```
Intent getCameraImage = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

File cameraFolder;

if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    cameraFolder = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"give_a_folder_name/camera");
else
    cameraFolder= StatusUpdate.this.getCacheDir();
if(!cameraFolder.exists())
    cameraFolder.mkdirs();

File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "give_a_folder_name/camera/camera_snap.jpg");
getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
initialURI = Uri.fromFile(photo);

startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, 2);
```

In this `onActivityResult()`:

```
targetURI = initialURI;
getContentResolver().notifyChange(targetURI, null);

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

try {

    // SET THE IMAGE FROM THE CAMERA TO THE IMAGEVIEW
    bmpImageCamera = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, targetURI);

    // SET THE IMAGE FROM THE GALLERY TO THE IMAGEVIEW
    imgvwSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(bmpImageCamera);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The targetURI and initialURI are Uri instances declared globally

Comment: I am taking this image from camera and storing into sdcard.Can I use this path,to post in graph api.If not possible,how can I convert into valid one

Comment: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera1354795516555.jpg old one   /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1354795516555.jpg   new one    Is it right?

Comment: I am using surfaceview,and one more thing is why cant I add the path of sdcard to graph api source tag.I think I have missed "/" between camera and file name.And did I need to add any permission.  I just want to know why it is not possible to add path of sdcard.